# Ruby: String showing up as string in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm working on a pig latin program on Ruby and was having some trouble.
The console shows this error

> ```
> expected: "appleay"
> got: ["appleay"]
> ```

```
def translate(str)

alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
consonants = alphabet - vowels

str.split.map do |word|
    if vowels.include?(word[0])
        word.to_str + "ay"

    elsif word[0..2].include?("qu")
        if word[0..1] == "qu"
            (word[2..-1] + "quay").join(" ")
        else
            word[3..-1] + word[0] + "quay"
        end
    elsif consonants.include?(word[0]) && consonants.include?(word[1]) && consonants.include?(word[2].to_s)
        word[3..-1] + word[0..2] + "ay"
    elsif consonants.include?(word[0]) && consonants.include?(word[1]) 
        word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + "ay"
    elsif cononants.include?(word[0])
        word[1..-1] + word[0] + "ay"

    else 
        word
    end
end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map). If you read the docs you can find:

> Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every
>   element in enum.

Since the return type is an Array, you are getting Array as result and not a String (which here happens to be the first element of the Array.)

A simple solution will be always to return the first element of the Array. You can achieve this by:

```
str.split.map do |word|
    if vowels.include?(word[0])
      ....
    else
      word
    end
end.first # returning the first element of resultant array, nil if none present
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Array#map`. This method returns an array. Since it is the last statement of your method `translate`, this array will implicitly returned. Thus, when you call the method it shall output an array. To fix this, do

```
str.split.map do |word|
    if vowels.include?(word[0])
        #...
    elsif word[0..2].include?("qu")
        #...
    end
end.join(' ')
```

This `join(' ')` will join each element into one string, each element separated by a single space (' '). This makes the output of the method a string instead of an array, fixing your problem while accounting for an array that is more than one element in size, unlike the other answer by shivam, which will only return the first element. It is more scalable this way.